# replace classes with library classes

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I have a quite large amount of java sources (an open Source Project), where i want to "patch" some class files with my own for debugging pruposes, without touching the original code.

So I made Patch-Project where i altered eg. com.package.abc.java

Now i want to tell eclipse and/or maven to build the original Project, but overwirte its own (original) com.package.abc.java from /src with the patched abc.java from my second Project, which i exported as a library.jar and added to /libs in the original Project.

The Stucture looks like this

```
Original:
/src
 com/package/
  abc.java
  def.java
/libs
 patch.jar

patch:
/src
 com/package/
  abc.java
```

How do i do this with eclipse and maven plugin?

Comment: Are you happy to edit the `pom.xml` file on the original project to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Side-Node: This would be a perfect case for Dependency injection.

But to solve your problem, use the [maven compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) and edit the pom of the open source project:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/src/main/java/com/package/abc.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Edit: If you don't want to edit the pom of the original project (this is a bit hacky in my opinion):

Create a profile in your ~/.m2/settings.xml which contains the plugin configuration:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>ig</id>
    <plugins>
      <!-- snippet from above -->
    </plugins>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

and then build the open source project with this profile:

```
mvn -Pig verify
```

Comment: Yes but as i said, i want to avoid touching the original Project as much as possible. Thank you for your answer, I can apparently accept after 8 minutes because of reasons^^

Comment: @billdoor Unfortunately [`<excludes>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#excludes) looks like a plugin parameter that can't be passed on the command line, based on the fact that there's no "User Property" defined for that parameter.

Comment: @billdoor see my edit. Be sure to not enable the profile when building your project. Furthermore there may be compilation errors because of missing files.